# How to change margin of the document title?

Tags: lyx, margins, titles

I want to move the title of my document up in order to save space. I can't figure out how to do this.

This is what I have in LyX

[image]

And this is how it shows up in PDF. I'd like to move it up.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to adhere to any style guide?  Do you want content on the same page as the title?  Table of contents?  You should try to be more specific :)  (By the way, welcome to TeX.SX!)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Although this is a LyX - based question: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [How to customize a title page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-add-a-flyleaf-code)

Comment: I don't have any table of contents and I'm not following any style guides. I do have a restriction to get everything in 12 pages and I am over 12 pages at the moment. So I thought I can move the title up and just begin my document on top of the first page rather than in the middle so that I can save overall space.

Comment: @birdy: So you're using the default Article class?

Comment: Yes, I am very new to LyX. I just started typing after installing it. So, I assume I'm just using the default.

Comment: @birdy: Most documents have a title page with title content only without additional text etc. content which belongs to *later* pages of the document. It's quite natural to have the title centered vertically. In addition, there are more information at the title, e.g. date/institution etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the default `Article (Standard Class)` (see you Document > Settings... > Document Class tab), the Title (Author and Date) is set using a macro called `\@maketitle` (inside [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls). This is what that macro looks like:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

You'll note that it inserts a `\newpage`, then sets `\null` (consider it just something to "start the page") and inserts a `v`ertical `skip` of `2em`, before starting to set the actual title (inside a `center`ed environment).

You can get rid of this vertical skip by adding the following to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\newpage\null\vskip 2em}{}% <search><replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

The above patch uses [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to remove the `\newpage \null \vskip 2em` construction from `\@maketitle`, thereby making the title start immediately where it's called. A similar thing can be added to remove the `v`ertical `skip` at the end of the environment (given by `\vskip 1.5em`), if needed:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\par\vskip 1.5em}{\par}% <search><replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

With only the first patch, your document should now resemble:

[image]

In the above output I've also added the [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) to highlight the position of the text box just as an indication that there's no white space set before the actual title.

With both patches active there's a little less space (not much) below the title:

[image]

Of course, instead of removing it, one can insert a negative space.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution has to be modified if using KOMA article class instead of the standard article class, because in the .cls, the command is not `\newpage\null\vskip 2em`, but `\null\vskip 2em`. Therefore

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\newpage\null\vskip 2em}{}% <search><replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

had to be changed to

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\null\vskip 2em}{}% <search><replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

to make it work (at least for me).

To reduce the space below the title without adding something to the preamble, I have found this solution [Reducing the space below the title](https://resourceful.github.io/latex/acm/usenix/template/2016/09/22/LaTeX-text-below-title/)

which in the document looks like

[image]

using Evil Red Code. That may be easier for someone new to LyX. It doesn't work for pushing the title up the page, however, only for decreasing the space between the subtitle, the date and the text.

No adjustment with `\vspace`
[image]

With adjusted `\vspace`

[image]